# Error after upgrading angularfire2 to @angular/fire

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I'm starting to get desperate, I have my little Angular 6 Application. I have upgraded from (I think it was) angularfire2 v3 to @angular/fire

I made all the changes according the upgrade from v4 to v5 (using and including the coresponding AngularFire libary) and i removed all AngularFireObservables/Objects

I still have a compiling error:

```
...

ERROR in Cannot read property 'getSymbolByModule' of undefined

ERROR in D:/Code/workouttracker/src/app/app.routes.ts (70,22): Generic type 'Mod
uleWithProviders<T, any>' requires 2 type argument(s).

ERROR in D:/Code/workouttracker/src/app/service/user.service.ts (27,24): 'fireba
se' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an
 import instead.
D:/Code/workouttracker/src/app/service/user.service.ts (28,27): 'firebase' refer
s to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import i
nstead.
D:/Code/workouttracker/src/app/service/user.service.ts (34,26): 'firebase' refer
s to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import i
nstead.
D:/Code/workouttracker/src/app/service/user.service.ts (39,26): 'firebase' refer
s to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import i
nstead.

ERROR in D:/Code/workouttracker/src/app/service/authguard.service.ts (8,31): Can
not find name 'AngularFireAuth'.
D:/Code/workouttracker/src/app/service/authguard.service.ts (12,14): Cannot find
 name 'Observable'.

ERROR in D:/Code/workouttracker/src/app/login/login.component.ts (19,20): Proper
ty 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Auth'.

ERROR in (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sockjs-client' in 'D:\Code\workouttracke
r\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client'
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1:13-37
 @ (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200
 @ multi webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200 ./src/main.ts
```

i alredy tried different versions of firebase and @angular/fire, i did a complete delete of node_modules and reinstalled it via npm install, here is my current package.json

```js
{
  "name": "workouttracker",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "strip-ansi": "^4.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.4.1",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Maybe you had something similar.

Angular: 6
Angular CLI: 1.0.0
Node JS: 8.12.0